# Why is subscribe not called after a groupBy operator?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Why is the subscribe-methode of the second example not called?

All logs within the pipe works as expected in both example.

WORKING EXAMPLE: (but using hardcoded data and of-creator):

---

```
of([
  {tableName: 'table1', firstName: 'name1', lastName: 'lastName1'},
  {tableName: 'table1', firstName: 'name2', lastName: 'lastName2'},
  {tableName: 'table2', firstName: 'name3', lastName: 'lastName3'},
  {tableName: 'table2', firstName: 'name4', lastName: 'lastName4'}
]).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log('amount of records', data.length)),
  mergeMap((searchResult) => searchResult),
  groupBy(b => b.tableName),
  mergeMap(group => {
    console.log('groupKey', group.key);
    return group.pipe(toArray());
  })
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

PROBLEM CODE: (using data directly from the ngrx-store and same data structure as the code working example above)

---

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(selectSearchResult),
  tap(data => console.log('amount of records', data.length)),
  mergeMap((searchResult) => searchResult),
  groupBy(b => b.tableName),
  mergeMap(group => {
    console.log('groupKey', group.key);
    return group.pipe(toArray());
  })
).subscribe(val => console.log(val)); // <- this is not called!?
```

I would like that the subscribe method is called for every group, as the
working example above with the hardcoded data. But the subscribe-method is ironically not called?!

[image]

Example of on item out of the array delivered by the store:

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example. Most likely the selector method doesn't select what you expect.

Comment: Hi:-) As I wrote the tap-operator after the selector logs the correct data I need already to the console. This is what really wiered is. Everthing in the problem code logs correctly to the console but only the subscribe-method is not called.
The selector returns an array of around 3000 items. I don't think this should be a problem?

Comment: Please log the data sent by the store and check if the data structure is identical to your first example.

Comment: Hi @ggradnig, I did it already. The data from the store is an [] of objects {}. Every objects has simply 4 string properties. You can expect, that it's the same principle as the working example. But as I mentioned, the stores array has around 3000 items.

Comment: The number of items shouldn't be a concern. Just to be sure: One of the string properties is `tableName` ?

Comment: Yes @ggradnig I think also that the amount of the items plays no role (but slowly I question everything :-O). Yes, there is in every object a property with the name of 'tableName'. I added a screenshot above from the console.

Comment: did you try to get an errormessage `.subscribe(val => console.log(val), err => console.error(err))`

Comment: Yes. I did everything. No error.
But I found out now, that it calls the subscription method, when I remove the toArray-operator at groupBy.pipe(toArray()).
But what the hell (sorry) works this with the hardcoded example???!!!
Do I understand something wrong with the groupBy-operator?

Comment: I suppose that `groupBy` will not emit any value until observable completes (like ForkJoin)

Comment: Hi @Sergey, thanks for your answer. Pls check my answer above your comment. Could it be something with the toArray-operator? When I remove the toArray-operator at groupBy.pipe(toArray()), the subscription call gets the values, but not as an array :-/
But what's the difference here to the working example at the top with the hardcoded values?

Comment: @OliverWaterkamp because `of` completes as soon as all values emitted whilst a real observable from Store doesn't complete. Many RxJs operators require observable completion and are not so obvious of their purpose so it's worh exploring docs. The best thing I found if `Ctrl+Click` in PhpStorm on operator which leads to typings file with tons of useful comments. I found there a lot of information that I didn't see anywhere in the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue lies here:

Store is a **long-living** Observable. This means: it won't **complete** by itself.

`toArray` collects all notifications of it's source stream until this stream **is complete** and only then sends single a notification with the array of items.

Otherwise, how would it know when an array is ready to be sent to the next operator? There could always be another notification that could make the array even larger.

Note that the `GroupedObservable` produced by `groupBy` will not complete until it's source is complete. Because the source `store` won't complete, `toArray` won't ever receive a `complete` message.

The solution is: Refactor your code so you get a completable observable with `from`. `from` takes an array as an argument, sends one notification for each array item and then sends a **complete notification**, indicating to `toArray` that it may send a notification. This should work:

```
mergeMap((searchResult) => 
  from(searchResult).pipe(
    groupBy(b => b.tableName),
    mergeMap(group => {
      console.log('groupKey', group.key);
      return group.pipe(toArray());
  })
))
```

Sources: [RxJS Code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/groupBy.ts) Have a look at when the GroupedObservable will complete.

Comment: thanks for your clear explaination. This makes completely sense what you said about the long-living observable of an store. I think I was thinking too much that I lost the focus. The observable of the store are always kind of listning to changes of the store. I seems I have refactore the code as you mentioned.

Comment: This is a nice solution but you should use switchMap not mergeMap and the functions should be up on the top level pipe, you should try and avoid nesting pipes.

Comment: You can't generally say use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`. It depends on what should be achieved. In this example, both variants could be possible and as this is a synchronous operation, it won't make a difference. Also, while you generally want to avoid nesting, it's not always possible. If you want to utilize the RxJS operators, you won't get around this.

Answer (score 0):

It think you are confusing groupBy as a function that works on arrays instead of a stream, RxJs functions apply to the stream, not the values that get emitted by the stream.

groupBy does not group arrays that get emitted by the stream, it groups the stream. As in each time the observable emits an object it is added to the group. If you want to group an array that is in the store you need a groupBy function that works with arrays.

Here is an example of a groupBy function I wrote that takes an array https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ezydzv

map is the RxJs function that manipulates the object emitted by the stream and in the map you can apply a groupBy to the array.

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(selectSearchResult),
  tap(data => console.log('amount of records', data.length)),
  map(data => groupBy(data, { keys: ['tableName'] }))
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```